# A simple formula in finite group representation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, fourier-transform

Let $G$ be a finite group and ${\rm Fun}(G)$ be the set of complex valued functions over $G$. There is an interesting algebra structure to be put on ${\rm Fun}(G)$, namely the convolution:

$$ (a \ast b )(x) := \Sigma_{g\in G} \,\, a(g)b(g^{-1}x)$$

One can show that the set of class functions ${\rm Class}(G)$ is a subalgebra under convolution. Therefore, by basic group representation theory, the convolution of two irreducible characters is a linear combination of irreducible characters.

I have computed for $\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z_2$ and $S_3$. And it seems that the general formula should be

$$ \chi_i \ast \chi_j = \frac{|G| \delta_{ij} \chi_i}{\dim(V_i)}.\tag{$\ast$}$$
However, I cannot prove it.

#### Attempts

1. I have computed for $\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z_2$ and $S_3$.
2. I have tried to use Fourier transform and inversion, but it amounts to prove the same thing at the end.
3. I have also skimmed through the basic texts in this field including Serre and Fulton+Harris, but fail to find a formula for this.

#### Question

Is the formula $(\ast)$ true in general? How do you prove if that's the case? It seems very simple and I apologize if I have overlooked a proof in basic texts. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your $Fun(G)$ is nothing but the group algebra $\mathbb C[G]$, and the convolution is the product in $\mathbb C[G]$. This is the standard fact that irreducible characters form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb C[G]$, which should be discussed in e.g. Serre.

Comment: I think Fun($G$) is more like the dual of $\mathbb{C}[G]$, but not itself. So if my statement is correct, it's simply asking to prove that under the duality, convolution corresponds to the group structure of $G$. This is exactly why I would like to prove it.

Comment: For a finite group $G$, there is no difference. There is an isomorphism from $Fun(G)$ to $\mathbb C[G]$ sending a function $f$ to $\sum_{g \in G} f(g)[g]$, where $[g]$ is the base element in $\mathbb C[G]$ corresponding to $g$.

Comment: I was aware of that as well.. but it seemed to me that the isomorphism and the "orthonormality" only reveals the value of $\chi_i \ast \chi_j$ at $e$.

Comment: Why only at $e$? If we identify $Fun(G)$ with $\mathbb C[G]$, then it is the regular representation of $G$ and we know that it decomposes as $\bigoplus_\chi V_\chi^{\dim \chi}$, with the irreducible characters $\chi$ (up to a scalar) as "projectors to the eigenspaces". Therefore $\chi_i\chi_j = 0$, except when $i = j$ and we have $\chi_i^2 = \chi_i$ (up to a scalar).

Comment: Thank you. This is a huge hint! I've always considered the regular representation as a $G$-module and forgets its algebra structure.

Comment: I have followed your advice and wrote a proof to my own answer below. Thank you very much.

Comment: Congratulations, and you're welcome (:

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Whatsup's useful comment in the original post, I now have a proof. I write it up here, with some references to Serre's *Linear Representations of Finite Groups*.

The algebra $(\operatorname{Fun}(G),\ast)$ is isomorphic to the group algebra $(\mathbb{C}[G],\cdot)$ simply by sending $\delta_x$ to $[x]$. Proposition 2.5.5 shows that $\mathbb{C}[G]$ decomposed to $\bigoplus_i V_i^{d_i}$ as a $G$-module, where $d_i = \dim V_i$. Theorem 2.6.8 further shows that the projector $p_i$ from $\mathbb{C}[G]$ to $V_i^{d_i}$ is given as an element in $\mathbb{C}[G]$ by

$$ p_i = \frac{d_i}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} \,\, \overline{\chi_i(g)} [g] .$$

The corresponding element in $\operatorname{Fun}(G)$ is then $\frac{d_i}{|G|}\overline{\chi_i}$. Therefore, since $p_i^2=p_i$, we have

$$ \frac{d_i^2}{|G|^2} \overline{\chi_i} \ast \overline{\chi_i} = \frac{d_i}{|G|}\overline{\chi_i}.$$

Finally, we get $$\chi_i\ast\chi_i = \frac{|G|}{d_i}\chi_i,$$ completing the proof.

Comment: Thank you for editing. I should sharpen my latex skill. Will keep your suggestions in mind!